# Jackson: should serialization change when class name changes and class inherits from another class?

Tags: java, jackson

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class OrigClass {
    private int fieldOne;
    private int field Two;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Let's say that I serialize an object of this class, and pass it read it by the class NewClass:

```
class NewClass extends BaseClass {
    private int fieldOne;
    // getters and setters
}

class BaseClass {
    private int field Two;
    // getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, an object of NewClass has exactly the same properties as the properties of OrigClass. The difference is that class names differ and NewClass inherits fieldOne from BaseClass. In this case, will an error occur in deserialization by NewClass?

Comment: Can you show you code and what error exactly you are getting ?

Comment: I didn't say that I get an error. I asked if Jackson should know how to handle such a case.

Comment: Did you try before posting? This should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the fields are inherited or not doesn't matter to Jackson, it will check for the setters.

If it can deserialize, it will. You should encounter no issues to serialize `OrigClass` and deserialize `NewClass`

Comment: only setter names affect serialization? getter names/property names has no effect?

Comment: Not only setter names, have a look at the annotations, and if you want advanced behaviour, you can have a look at the custom serializers/deserializers.